# Gradle explode a zip into a buildDir

Tags: gradle

My project has a remote dependency which is really just a zip of certain files, which needs to be unzipped somewhere, so that the build can generate new java sources from the files.  (I'm speaking generically to focus on the core problem and not on the specifics)

I wouldn't expect this to be so hard, but I've been unable to get it working.  Here's what I've created:

I defined a new configuration:

```
configurations {
    newConf
}
```

Later, I've defined a single dependency for this confiuguration.  It resolves to the zip file I need to explode:

```
dependencies {
    newConf "group:name:version@zip"
}
```

So far this all smells correct to me, though if anybody disagrees, I'm listening.

Lastly I need to define a task that explodes the zip into a directory, which then becomes the input for a later code-generation command.

```
task explodeModel {
    description = "unzip model into the specified 'modelSrc' directory"

    //input is a "files" collection (usually just one:  the zip)
    //output is the specified modelSrc dir

    File modelSrc = new File("$buildDir/modelSrc")
    outputs.files modelSrc

    doLast {
        configurations.newConf.allArtifacts.each { artifact -> println artifact }
    }

}
```

Obviously doLast isn't unzipping anything just yet, I'm just trying to get an absolute path to the zipfile itself, and thats where I'm stuck.  I have no idea how to get a path to the file so I can unzip it.  Any help?

Many thanks

Comment: I think if you just want the paths you can use something like configurations.newConf.files.each { println it }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did something similar in a plugin that I wrote. This should work for you:

```
configurations.newConf.singleFile
```

The assumption is that there's only one file. The return type is `java.io.File`.
For more information check this class [GaePlugin.groovy](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/gae/GaePlugin.groovy). The method of relevance is `configureDownloadSdk`. The task that does the unzip is [GaeDownloadSdkTask.groovy](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-gae-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/plugins/gae/task/GaeDownloadSdkTask.groovy).

Comment: Thanks so much, this works for me.  I do wonder if there is a solution that works for multiple dependencies, so I will see if somebody else offers one, otherwise the check-mark goes to you!  One question:  I don't see "singleFile" anywhere in the docs, I'd expect it as a property or method on [Configuration](http://gradle.org/current/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html).  Was there someplace I was supposed to be able to find this myself?

Comment: The method [getSingleFile()](http://gradle.org/current/docs/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getSingleFile()) is actually coming from FileCollection. The interface Configuration extends FileCollection. In case you expect multiple dependencies you can use the method [getFiles()](http://gradle.org/current/docs/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getFiles()) instead.

Comment: Hi , could you please tell me where is `$buildDir` with Gradle

Comment: It's defined in [org.gradle.api.Project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getBuildDir()).

Answer (score 12):

Try something along these lines, it should work:

```
task explodeModel(type: Copy){
  configurations.newConf.filter { it.toString().endsWith(".zip") }.each{
    from zipTree(it)
  }
  into 'output/dir'
}
```

Of course, you can omit the `.zip` filtering part if you are sure that artifacts in the configuration are zips.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've been doing lately, and I've been happy with it:
*(This example assumes a configuration called `zipFiles` that includes only ZIP files.)*

```
ext.unpackedZipFiles = fileTree("$buildDir/unpackedZipFiles") { builtBy 'unpackZipFiles' }
task unpackZipFiles(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.zipFiles.files.collect { zipTree(it) }
    into unpackedZipFiles.dir
}
```

---

#### Details

There are several things I enjoy about this approach:

1. Instead of having the magic string `"$buildDir/unpackedZipFiles"` sprinkled throughout the build, the output of the unzip is represented by an actual `FileTree`. This makes using the output in future copy-like tasks quite simple:

   ```
   aCopyLikeTask(type: Copy) {
       from unpackedZipFiles
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Tasks that use the unzipped files don't depend directly on the task that unzips the files. Rather they depend on the `FileTree` itself, which knows how to unzip the files. Note that `FileTree` extends `Buildable`, and so can be a dependency of a task:

   ```
   aNonCopyTask(dependsOn: unpackedZipFiles) << {
       // ... do stuff that references unpackedZipFiles.dir
   }
   ```
3. `Project.fileTree()` actually returns a `ConfigurableFileTree`, which is why we can specify one *or more* tasks that it is built by. This interface also provides the `File` of the root of the tree via the `dir` property, which is often handy. For example:

   ```
   myExecTask(dependsOn: unpackedZipFiles) << {
       "${unpackedZipFiles.dir}/bin/runMe".execute([], unpackedZipFiles.dir)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

My solution (adapted to our code) would be something along the lines of

```
task explodeModel(type: Copy) {
    configurations.newConf.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        if (artifact.file.name.endsWith('.zip')) {
            from zipTree(artifact.file)
            into '.'
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that it works against the *resolved* (as opposed to *requested*) artifacts.